# A paper by Y. Morita

Tags: reference-request, abstract-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

The corresponding bibliographical details are:

Yoshihito Morita, *Elementary proofs of the commutativity of rings satisfying* $x^{n}=x$. Mem. Defense Acad. 18 (1978), no. 1, 1–24.

Does anybody here know if there is a retro-digitized copy of it somewhere on the internet?

In the case that it is not available online but **you happen to own a hard copy of the paper**, would you be so kind as to **share with me an electronic copy of it**?

Please, let me thank you in advance for the attentiveness of your replies.

Comment: A photocopy of it should be arriving in my mail in a matter of days. I'll share it when I get it.

Comment: @lenticcatachresis: Hi!

Comment: Hi! I didn't forget about it, it just took a while to arrive in my mail. I have it now. I'd share it here, but Carlo points out below that there are copyright restrictions. 
On an unrelated note, if I had your email address, I could send you *a greeting card* ;) (edit: oh wait, it's right there on your profile)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked [before,](http://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=200035&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) the answer at that time was to ask a library to send it to you, and I guess that's still the way to go; here is a link to [some libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/memoirs-of-the-defense-academy-mathematics-physics-chemistry-and-engineering/oclc/1795203) that have it.

The journal has been scanned by [Hathitrust Digital Library](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000496119), but cannot be made available online because of copyright restrictions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time to reply, Mr. Beenakker... Do you know why it is that I have this feeling that Martin_Infinite might be the same individual as MO's very own Martin Brandenburg?

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. This is no secret ;-)
PS: Let me know if your request is still relevant. I have the article here on my desk.